# Understanding strip()

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

I am trying the strip() method on this string but it doesn't give the desired output.

```
s = 'www.yahoo.com'
s = s.rstrip('.com') 
print s     # The desired output is 'www.yahoo' but this is showing 'www.yah'
```

Along with the solution please provide the reason for current output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`str.strip('.com')`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) removes specified characters `.`, `c`, `o`, `m`, not `.com` at the beginning and at the end of the string.

To remove `.com`, use [`str.replace`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace).

```
>>> s = 'www.yahoo.com'
>>> s.replace('.com', '')  # Replace `.com` with empty string.
'www.yahoo'
```

**UPDATE**

As Marcin Fabrykowski,  David Zwicker pointed, above solution will turn `www.company.com` into `wwwpany`.

To address that, you can use Marcin Fabrykowski's solution. Or [using regular expression](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html):

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'\.com$', '', 'www.company.com')
'www.company'
>>> re.sub(r'\.com$', '', 'www.company.com.com')
'www.company.com'
```

---

```
>>> re.sub(r'(\.com)+$', '', 'www.company.com.com')  # To remove multiple trailings.
'www.company'
```

`\.com$` matches `.com` at the end of the string (`$`). `.` is escaped becasue `.` has a special meaning in the regular expression (match any character).

**NOTE** I used `r'raw string literal'`; `r'\.com' == '\\.com'`

Comment: This would turn `www.company.com` in `wwwpany`, which is hardly ever what you want. Marcin's answer is probably a better solution.

Comment: @DavidZwicker, Marcin's answer has a same problem because it also use `str.replace`. Anyway, thank you for pointing out that. I will update the answer to suggest more robust solution.

Comment: Nope, his first part gives the right solution. The second part is there to illustrate why your solution does not work. Admittedly, that is not very clearly written in his answer.

Comment: Updated the answer to address that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

you can try:

```
if x.endswith('.com'): print(x[:-4])
```

becouse:

```
x = "www.computers.com"
print(x.replace('.com',''))
wwwputers
```